# how to pass the id of that row[0] from the table to my confirmation dialog

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

how can i pass the specific row from my table to my confirmation dialog which is to delete. my algorithm is, when i click that row, its href is going to my popup dialog, then when click yes, that is where to delete that row, but everytime i click yes, it always click on the first row, not to the specific row.

heres my php code

```
         <?php

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)    {
        while(($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))){
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div class='name'><a href='profile.php?id=$row[0]' title='Open Profile'>$row[1], $row[2] $row[3]</a>                                        
        </div></td>


        <td width='150px'>
        <div class='button-group'>
        <a class='button icon edit' href='edit.php?id=$row[0]'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit&nbsp;&nbsp;<a/>
        <a class='button danger icon remove' href='#popup2'>Delete<a/>


        </div>

        <div id='popup2' class='overlay'>
            <div class='popup'>

                <h3>Are you sure you want to Delete?</h3>
                <a class='close' href='#'>&times;</a>
                <div class='content'>
                <div class='yes'>   
                <li><a href='delete.php?id=$row[0]' >Yes</a></li>
                </div>
                <div class='no'>    
                <li><a href='#' >No</a></li>
                </div>


                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </td>
                </tr>
    ";
}
   }
    ?>
```

Comment: you should not specify the same id for multiple element in html. In your case `<div id='popup2' class='overlay'>` will be placed multiple times in your page as you have used it inside loop. Try to make the popup box id also as dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

You have given a same name to all the popups that you are generating in the while loop.

```
    <a class='button danger icon remove' href='#popup2?id=$row[0]'>Delete<a/>

    <div id='popup2' class='overlay'>
        <div class='popup'>

            <h3>Are you sure you want to Delete?</h3>
            <a class='close' href='#'>&times;</a>
            <div class='content'>
            <div class='yes'>   
            <li><a href='delete.php?id=$row[0]' >Yes</a></li>
            </div>
            <div class='no'>    
            <li><a href='#' >No</a></li>
            </div>


            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

So, all the popups will point to the first `#popup2` all the buttons are pointing to the same id. So, for your solution to work you should add a unique id for every popup.

The better way to implement this is by using Jquery and Ajax to implement the deletion logic.

Alternative, way to do it by Jquery.

Generate the table and keep the popup box outside the while loop.

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)    {

    while(($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))){
    echo "
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div class='name'><a href='profile.php?id=$row[0]' title='Open Profile'>$row[1], $row[2] $row[3]</a>                                        
        </div></td>


        <td width='150px'>
        <div class='button-group'>
        <a class='button icon edit' href='edit.php?id=$row[0]'>&nbsp;&nbsp;Edit&nbsp;&nbsp;<a/>
        <a class='button danger icon remove' value=$row[0] href='#popup2'>Delete<a/>


        </div>
       </td>
       </tr>";
}
```

Add a value parameter to a href.

```
 <div id='popup2' class='overlay'>
    <div class='popup'>

        <h3>Are you sure you want to Delete?</h3>
        <a class='close' href='#'>&times;</a>
        <div class='content'>
        <div class='yes'>   
        <li id="dynamic"><a href='delete.php?id=$row[0]' >Yes</a></li>
        </div>
        <div class='no'>    
        <li><a href='#' >No</a></li>
        </div>


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, Jquery part.

```
$('.remove').on('click', function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    var html = "<a href='delete.php?id="+value+"' >Yes</a>";
    $('#dynamic').html(html);
});
```

Dynamically update the `a href` link in the popup box.